# Get a tuple value in a tuple by index

Tags: python, django, tuples, django-cms

for a Django Model i needed an extra field to set a special month. This was done with the choices attribute an a tuple set:

```
class Timeline(models.Model):

    MONTHS = (
        (1, _("January")),
        (2, _("February")),
        (3, _("March")),
        (4, _("April")),
        (5, _("May")),
        (6, _("June")),
        (7, _("July")),
        (8, _("August")),
        (9, _("September")),
        (10, _("October")),
        (11, _("November")),
        (12, _("December")),
    )

    tldate_mth = models.IntegerField(_("Month"), choices=MONTHS, default=1)
```

In admin section this works fantastic. Now i want to output the month in my template:

```
 # ...
 def to_string(self):
    return "%s (%s / %d)" % (self.title, self.MONTHS.index(self.tldate_mth), self.tldate_yr)
```

But then i got the message "tuple.index(x): x not in tuple". What did i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides you a shortcut do to this: `self.get_tldate_mth_display()`.

(The reason your code failed is that that isn't at all what `.index()` does; you should just do `self.MONTHS[self.tldate_mth-1][1]`; but, as I say, there's no need to do that when there's a built-in way already.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def to_string(self):
    return "%s (%s / %d)" % (self.title, [month[0] for month in self.MONTHS].index(self.tldate_mth), self.tldate_yr)
```

Django stores only the first value of the tuple (values 1-12 in this case) for choices field.